# OpenBLAS needed for CNN using Theano on windows & CPU

Tags: python, numpy, theano, openblas

I'm getting this error([here](https://github.com/Vivek-B/Kaggle/blob/master/Digit%20Recognition/Conv-2D%20--%20Keras.ipynb)) while trainng a convolutional Neural Network in keras. (ipython on Windows 8.1).

I've checked the numpy cofiguration. It says it has blas_mkl but no OpenBLAS. Is blas_mkl not sufficient?

I was trying to install OpenBLAS by following the steps from theano's page ([here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows)):

1. I was not able to compile OpenBLAS with **"quickbuild.win32 1>log.txt 2>err.txt"** command from MinGW shell/cmd. a dialogue box poped up saying to choose a program to run it.
2. Hence, couldn't extract libopenblas.dll
3. And its very unclear as to how to modify the .theanorc or .theanorc.txt

Could someone please help me to install OpenBLAS on windows so that I can work with keras on ipython.

Comment: Could you specify what is your Windows Python installation? Have you installed Python by Anaconda package? Have any model ever worked on your system?

Comment: Yes, I've installed python from Anaconda. There were no issues faced while training normal Neural nets in keras. I faced this issue only while trying convolutional nets

Comment: What version of Anaconda do you have?

Comment: Anaconda2-4.0.0 for windows 64 bit and python 2.7

Comment: In this case - this has a MKL Libraries installed. So you should try to set theano.config.openmp = True.

Comment: I tried **theano.config.openmp = True** at the beginning of the code. It didn't work. If I can compile OpenBLAS with mingw and extract libopenblas.dll, I think the problem would be solved. But I'm not able to do this.

Comment: Have you seen this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965010/theano-cnn-on-cpu-abstractconv2d-theano-optimization-failed

Comment: Yes, I've seen the question. mingw in my system doesn't have msys. So I used cygwin to extract libopenblas.dll. I've set theano.config.blas.ldflags = "-LX:\\YYY\\YYY -lopenblas" as suggested by theano's installation guide. Now, when I run the CNN in keras, it is showing "DLL load failed" error. LInk: https://github.com/Vivek-B/Kaggle/blob/master/Digit%20Recognition/Conv-2D_Keras.ipynb

Comment: And it hasn't helped?